# Annual percentage interest rate

Tags: finance

An annual percentage interest rate of $30\%$ is equivalent to a monthly compound interest rate closest

A) $2.02\%$

B) $2.21\%$

C) $2.50\%$

D) $2.66\%$

The answer is B
Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: The idea here is to equate the principal at time $t$ if the account earns an annual percentage rate of $30\%$ with the principal at time $t$ if the account earns an annual percentage rate of $100r\%$ compounded monthly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$(1+0.0221)^{12}\approx 1.30$$

Comment: Can you show the solution please.

Comment: you can check it by calculator

Comment: It's there another way to solve it without the calculator

Comment: No you need to calculate in some way, also binomial approximation $(1+x^a)\approx 1+ax$ leads to the wrong result 2.50%. The calculation is simple, we just need to iterate 12 times the multiplication by (1.0221).